# Submitting Jobs to Linux Workstation

Tags: linux

I have access to some Linux Workstations on which I run my 
C++ executable files from my Laptop but the problem is that 
each time I run a job from the terminal in my laptop I have 
to keep a terminal window for each job ... I need a way to 
submit the job to the Linux machine and see the result once 
only after the execution finishes ... I know that this can 
be done in FORTRAN executable by adding & at the end only and
I tried it with:
mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000&
and
mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000 &
but non of them is working ...

Is there anyway to do the same in Linux ??

Answer (score 2):

How about using the screen command?

Answer (score 2):

as other have said you can run them in `screen` or `tmux`. You can also look at `nohup`

```
  nohup mpirun -np 20 ./a 200 1000000 &  > output.log 2>&1
```

Since without something like `nohup` you cannot exit the sessions with jobs running in the background, or they will stop running when the Shell sends a `HUP` signal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tmux` or the older `screen` to maintain a terminal session on the remote server, to which you can attach and detach at will. Check the documentation for each command for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a lot of jobs and would like to have a queue onto which jobs can be placed. I would recommend using something like [redis](https://github.com/resque/resque), but the screen/tmux method is pretty solid too.